# ID auto increase but not unique

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have a table that I want to have an id that will auto increase itself but not be primary or unique.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "not be primary or unique"?

Comment: you can have id, not_uniuqe_id,other keys

Comment: I'm logging calls, and some calls have couple of lines of history, meaning the same call (id) needs a few rows

Comment: as I mentioned above...

Comment: make history a text field, and put as much text in it as you like, your not limited to 1 line

Comment: please improve your question with a bit better description of what you are trying to achieve in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really create another table, in that case.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE `Calls` (
  `Id`     INT(10)      AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `From`   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `To`     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `CallHistory` (
  `Id`     INT(15)      AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CallId` INT(10)      NOT NULL,
  `Text`   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `CallHistory_Calls_idx` (`CallId`),
  CONSTRAINT `CallHistory_Calls`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CallId`)
    REFERENCES `calls` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here's [a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d832b/6) on SQLFiddle.

A benefit of this is that if you delete a row from `Calls`, the rows in `CallHistory` will also be deleted.

---

Running this query:

```
SELECT `Calls`.`Id`,
       `Calls`.`From`,
       `Calls`.`To`,
       `CallHistory`.`Text`

FROM   `Calls`, `CallHistory`
WHERE  `Calls`.`Id` = `CallHistory`.`CallId`;
```

Gives results something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Anyway I don't see how it wouldn't stay unique unless you update existing values later

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set `auto_increment` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `testID` int(11) NOT NULL, //primary key here
  `testInc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, //here is your non-primary auto increment column
  PRIMARY KEY (`testID`),
  KEY `testInc` (`testInc`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and if you want this to be unique also then you may add unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD CONSTRAINT ux_unique_constraint UNIQUE `testInc`
```